# Karma test using fontawesome - "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.10.0", in a template throws errors on console

Tags: angular

I am writing a isolated unit test for a component which has the following template (including the font awesome icons).

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col text-center">
      <span id="copyright">All rights reserved. Copyright @ 2019</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <a class="col-sm-2" href="">
      <fa-icon [icon]="['fab', 'blogger']" class="border-bottom" [spin]="true"></fa-icon>
    </a>
    <a class="col-sm-2" href="">
      <fa-icon [icon]="['fab', 'twitter']" class="border-bottom" [spin]="true"></fa-icon>
    </a>
    <a class="col-sm-2" href="">
      <fa-icon [icon]="['fab', 'linkedin']" [pulse]="true" class="border-bottom"></fa-icon>
    </a>
    <a class="col-sm-2" href="">
      <fa-icon [icon]="['fab', 'git']" [spin]="true" class="border-bottom"></fa-icon>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

My versions in package.json are as under

```sh
"@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.4.0",
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.20",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.10.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.10.0",
```

My application runs fine, but when I execute a simple test I get errors in console

```sh
ERROR: 'FontAwesome: Could not find icon with iconName=blogger and prefix=fab'
Chrome 74.0.3729 (Mac OS X 10.14.6): Executed 5 of 14 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.37 secs)
ERROR: 'FontAwesome: Could not find icon with iconName=twitter and prefix=fab'
Chrome 74.0.3729 (Mac OS X 10.14.6): Executed 5 of 14 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.37 secs)
ERROR: 'FontAwesome: Could not find icon with iconName=linkedin and prefix=fab'
Chrome 74.0.3729 (Mac OS X 10.14.6): Executed 5 of 14 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.37 secs)
ERROR: 'FontAwesome: Could not find icon with iconName=git and prefix=fab'
```

I have already added the module

```sh
imports: [FontAwesomeModule]
```

But the console errors still persists, though the test is passing.

I am just looking for options to ensure the errors go away and to understand the correct way of adding these icon definitions to a component.

Comment: If you are writing an isolated unit test, does it actually matter for that test, that the component ```<fa-icon>``` does what is does? Or is it sufficient that font awesome probably tested the component, and you only would like to ensure, that a font-icon tag is inside your component with specific params?

Comment: Logically what  you said is right, but call me OCD I hate looking at the warnings and errors that are appearing, and just wanted to understand how the testing engine can be supplied with the required information to get rid of these errors outputted in console.

Comment: Yes I understood that, I was just asking whether it would be sufficient to use a shallow testing approach using ```NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA```. If it is sufficient this would definitely resolve the error as well, but would not exactly be the answer to your initial question why the test runs through but gives you the error.

Comment: Having a look at the [documentation](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome) of the angular font awesome module I guess you would need to add all icons used using ```library.add(...)```. But being this a unit test, imho I would probably rather have a look into [shallow component testing](https://angular.io/guide/testing#nested-component-tests) to avoid setting up things not actually relevant for your test cases.

Comment: I utilized the ```library.add``` approach also, adding them globally to a suite is helping resolve all the font awesome errors that are reported, and if I use it within ```beforeEach``` it sometimes throws errors in console.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it looks like library.add should do.

Comment: So did ```import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { faBlogger, faTwitter, faGit, faLinkedin } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons';``` and also added ```library.add(faGit, faLinkedin, faBlogger, faTwitter);``` globally in the app.component.spec.ts with ```imports: [FontAwesomeModule]``` also defined; it helped solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For template errors it's not necessary to include the module that's throwing the error. You can simply ignore multiple modules error on templates by using `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA from @angular/core`

in you spec.ts file

```
    import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core'

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          declarations: [Component],
          schemas:[ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
        })
          .compileComponents();
```

Comment: I was suggesting that, twice I think, too. Because it just makes more sense to test the own component instead of what the font awesome component does and needs. But for some reason adding the library was the preferred solution :/

Comment: @Erbsenkoenig I tried both the solutions; the one with the shallow testing was quick and easy but with library add I was able to avoid the scope of any template errors while adding and consuming the fa-icons so preferred that.